# Как сделать отступы между строками в тексте средствами css?

Tags: html, css

[image: Такие отступы нужны]

[image: а вот как это выглядит сейчас]

Как сделать отступы именно между строками, а не словами?

```
            <p class="left_block__p">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud eur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Sed ut uptatem.</p>
```

```
.left_block__p{
    font-family: 'roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #666666;
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 95px;
    letter-spacing:0.2ex
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.left_block__p{
    line-height: 20px
}
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогли

Answer (score 2):

Свойство [`line-height`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/line-height) устанавливает высоту строк и расстояние между ними

Comment: спасибо большое, помогли